# Are all Note 7 phones to be returned?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-7

I have applied to court to return my Samsung Note 7 to the retailer who refused to take it back and return my money (a necessity in my country by law)

The court decided that an expert should decide if returning the phone is necessary or not.

Expert report said that my Note 7 is not up for recall by Samsung and therefore my demand was denied by the court.

I read it that all Note 7 phones should be returned but expert decided otherwise, stating that it only includes phones that are sold by Samsung and not retailers, and not all phones but only a subseries has this problem and my phone wasn't one of them.

Is he right? Not from the legal aspects but the tech part. I thought all Samsung Note 7s were possibly risky.

Comment: Call Samsung representatives to your rescue. The recall is as serious as it can be - Samsung is going as far as permanently disabling _all_ N7s still in hands.

Comment: I agree with Andy here. I really don't know about any lists announced by Samsung about a subseries. For all I know, they are called back. Consumer protection laws of EU should protect your rights if you are from EU or a country that acts by European Human Rights Agreement. Since Samsung called the devices back, the device is obviously problematic. Try to contact Samsung if retailer is official. If not, if you can, object to court ruling and take it to Higher Court.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal issues and recalls, not Android use.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung is pushing out Updates that disable the Charging ability of your phone so it becomes useless.

Samsung stated that every Note 7 should be returned regardless of the Place you bought it from. I would suggest that you contact Samsung about that problem and see if they can help.